# Sci-fi adventure graphic novel: girl and her giant mouse companion face various robots, including a spherical one and one with many tendrils

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots

I remember reading a sci-fi adventure-drama graphic novel in elementary school that had a simplistic and cartoony art style. I believe that the main protagonist was a girl and she had a giant mouse companion who wore a device that translated his mouse noises into words on paper.

I also remember a floating spherical droid that was similar to [V.I.N.CENT from *The Black Hole* (1979)](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/V.I.N.CENT) and an antagonistic robot that appeared as a mass of thread-thin tendrils coming out of a scubadiving helmet.

There was also a broken robot who was revealed to be a starkilling superweapon.

Despite my best efforts, I cannot find anything close to this novel online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*Zita the Spacegirl*](https://us.macmillan.com/series/zitathespacegirl/) (2011) by Ben Hatke.

> When her best friend gets abducted by an evil alien cult, Zita’s life takes a turn for the cosmic and she finds herself on a strange planet inhabited by humanoid chickens and neurotic robots. Zita’s determination to find her way back home to earth has her assuming the role of intergalactic hero in this delightful, action-packed science fiction series.

The cover shows the elements you described.

[image: comic cover. Cartoony smiling girl with short brown hair standing on top of a metal installation. Her outfit is mostly white, with a black Z and a green cape. The background features the mouse companion, a little spherical robot, a semmingly scared blonde boy, and tendrils coming out of a diving suit's helmet]

Comment: AH YES! THAT'S IT. Thank you so much!